# Unattended-Upgrade configuration time used

Tags: unattended-upgrades

While configuring Unattended-Upgrades, the "/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades" file contains the following:

> // If automatic reboot is enabled and needed, reboot at the specific
> // time instead of immediately //  Default: "now"
> //Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-Time "02:00";

I need to determine if the "02:00" references UTC time or local machine time?
For that matter with the utilization of systemd does time settings in this config file matter when utilizing systemd "/lib/systemd/system/apt-daily.timer" settings?

Answer (score 1):

*systemd* defaults to parsing dates in the local timezone unless told otherwise. Excerpt of its [time format documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.time.html#Parsing%20Timestamps):

> **The timezone defaults to the current timezone if not specified
> explicitly**. It may be given after a space, like above, in which case
> it can be: "`UTC`", an entry in the installed IANA timezone database
> ("`CET`", "`Asia/Tokyo`", &c.; complete list obtainable with
> "`timedatectl list-timezones`" (see timedatectl(1))), or "`±05`",
> "`±0530`", "`±05:30`", "`Z`".

So any date given to *systemd* that doesn't state a timezone will be in local timezone.

In addition, `"now"` means a reboot would be triggered at the end of *unattended-upgrade* **upgrade** operations **which depends on `apt-daily-upgrade.timer`**, **not on `apt-daily.timer`** which only does the update part of the operations:

```
$ systemctl cat apt-daily.service | grep ^ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily update
$ systemctl cat apt-daily-upgrade.service | grep ^ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily install
```

Typically by default the update operation runs twice a day, the upgrade/install operation once a night.

When a reboot is deemed necessary, `unattended-upgrade` will run the `shutdown` command as seen below since it's a python script:

```
$ grep /sbin/shutdown /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
    cmd = ["/sbin/shutdown", "-r", when]
```

The `shutdown` command, provided by *systemd* or not, has its own syntax and rules for time format (for compatibility) and will not accept any arbitrary date, but only some limited formats, including `now`, `hh:mm`  in the current local timezone, and a few other formats described in `shutdown(8)`. `unattended-upgrade` will just copy the parameter provided in its configuration file, so this has to be valid for the `shutdown` command.

One should probably avoid a time that could be in the period during a timezone change if it's important in the setup to be sure when it will actually be done (eg: in the CET (Central European Time) timezone choosing 02:30 might possibly miss such reboot during the CET to CEST timezone transition where 02:00 will step to 03:00, depending on how `shutdown` and its specific *systemd* implementation behave, even though I'd be surprised this isn't accounted for). `now` is always safe in this regard.